# What does MapReduceCommand.OutputType REDUCE do in MapReduce command in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am using `collection.mapReduce(MapReduceCommand command)` for running a MapReduce job.

`MapReduceCommand` has an `enum` input OutputType. Which can be:

1. REPLACE
2. MERGE
3. REDUCE
4. INLINE

Documentation says:

> `public static final MapReduceCommand.OutputType MERGE`
>
> Merge the job output with the existing contents of outputTarget
>   collection
>
> `public static final MapReduceCommand.OutputType REDUCE`
>
> Reduce the job output with the existing contents of outputTarget
>   collection

What exactly OutputType.REDUCE does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody answered, So I asked this on [MongoDB-User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user)

Say `cars` is your *outputcollection* (where you want to store output of map-reduce job).

- REPLACE: If your current MR is successful, all of the documents in `cars` will be deleted (regardless of their _id) and replaced by the current result.
- MERGE: No document in `cars` will be deleted. Instead, each document in your current result will replace an already existing document in `cars` with the same _id. If there is not any document in `cars` with that _id, it will be just inserted. You can see this like an upsert:

  ```
  db.cars.update({_id: newDocument._id}, {value: newDocument.value}, {upsert: true})
  ```
- REDUCE: This is very similar to MERGE. But instead of just replacing the existing document, both documents will be the input of your reduce function (i.e. reduce([oldDocument, newDocument])) and the resulting document will replace the existing one.
- INLINE: Returns your result as a variable in the same fashion a function does. Nothing is stored in MongoDB, so this does not impact any collection.

The complete answer can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/U0xUAnAwU2g).